# Fixing Normals on Mesh

Tags: modeling, python, normals, normal-map

So I am working on project for school and this is a software project so I have had to spend a good chunk learning the ins and outs of Blender, so I am no expert in the field.

But I seam to be having issues with getting these normals on the mesh right, like when you zoom out you will see lots of red dots all over the mesh and as you get closer some still remain as dots and others look to be folded faces which I have been able to solve most of, but it's like the vertex that is attached to a face is pointing the wrong direction. I have tried nearly all the normal fixing options and can't seem to get it to point the right way?

I would love some help in how to tackle this as I need the mesh to be useable for the next part of my study, so ideally a quick fix whether it be annoying to implement would be nice or something to point me in the right direction.

Quick background of what I am allowed to talk about on the project is I am taking very high polygon mesh data about 16 million triangles after duplicate and overlapping data is removed so was much higher and the same in materials, which I have reduced to just 6 textures and then running my code to output a better mesh that is cleaner less polygons etc. but still of high quality, and while I have reduced the number significantly 5.5 million faces and 11 million triangles, there is still a lot to process so doing by hand of manually flipping is a no go.

**Ultimately how do I go about fixing these sorts of normals or is there a way to remove the normals all together and then bake the texture that will create the normals for it?**
(*scripting is preferred but any technique that will solve it is fine as I am sure I can turn it into a script*)

**Reduced Mesh Normal Orientation**
[image: Reduced Mesh]

**Reduced Mesh Geometry Settings**
[image: Reduced Mesh Geometry Settings]

**High Poly Mesh Normal Orientation**
[image: High Poly Mesh Normal Orientation]